# Project based Finder window presets

Tags: macos, finder, software-recommendation, smart-folders

Does anyone know of software that would allow me to pull up a set of finder windows based on a project type.  I'm a user experience manager who's constantly switching between projects and it would be awesome to be able to select "cart/checkout redesign" and it brings up all folders right where I left them.  Finder windows are just the start to this dream tool of mine.  Would love to be able to pull up everything right where I left them: files, applications, emails, etc.  Almost like having a different computer for each project.
I've researched the heck out of this and have found nothing like this.  Spaces doesn't do it.  There's lots of tools for managing windows but none that will pull up a set of windows and file locations based on a preset.  "Finder Window Manager" is an old piece of software that sounded promising, but it didn't work at all given what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have a look at [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) - it might go some way toward what you need. It doesn't do windows, but it does folder locations/defaults in switchable sets

Answer (score 1):

Apple's solution for this is to use Mission Control (if you need multiple desktops) and Finder Tags for each file/project.

From there, you can use finder's tag filtering and/or smart folders to assemble your views.

Also, saving these to your Favorites and removing things you don't use make quick access to these "views" possible across finder and other app open/save dialogs.

Lastly, look at [Divvy](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/divvy-window-manager/id413857545?mt=12) to automate window placement - it's very scriptable and you might use [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/launchbar) or another tool to speed actions if spotlight isn't action oriented enough for your automation.